# pisignage API login error: "This username/email is not registered or active"

Tags: python-3.x, api, python-requests

From there [api docs](https://piathome.com/apidocs/), I have created a request to login and get the token. The code is under below, it returns 401 . The credentials are right and I can log in from web, but through API I can not.

```
import requests
import json

params_dict = {
    "email": "example@mail.com",
    "password": "example",
    "getToken": True
    }

response = requests.post(
    'https://example.piathome.com/api/session',
    data=params_dict
    # headers={'Content-type': 'application/json', 'accept': 'application/json'} returns 500
)

json_response = response.json()

print(json_response)
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the API endpoint is set to username.pisignage.com (not just pisignage.com).

And the headers are absolutely required. Request and Response types must be set to `application/json`.